# Complex path query with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a sentence graph in neo4j and I would like to know how to do a complex query that would start and end with a node with the :WORD label and return a path between them.

The point is that I want it to have varying length and only return paths that goes through nodes with certain properties. I would like something like:

```
MATCH p=((p1:Word)-[r*0..4](***)-(p2:Word))
WHERE v:Variable {property = value} 
RETURN p1,p2,p AS Path, length(p) AS PathSize 
ORDER BY PathSize
```

***: Here I would like to name the nodes of the middle of the path as v and filter only the paths where the v's have a certain property. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
MATCH p=(p1:Word)-[*0..4]-(p2:Word)
WHERE ALL(v IN NODES(p) WHERE v.property = value)
RETURN p1, p2, p AS Path, LENGTH(p) AS PathSize 
ORDER BY PathSize;
```

Comment: getting this: 

Type mismatch: expected Path but was Collection<Relationship> (line 1, column 61 (offset: 60))

"MATCH p=((p1:Word)-[r*0..2]-(p2:Word)) WHERE ALL(v IN NODES(r) WHERE v.pos = "NN") RETURN p1,p2,p AS Path, length(p) AS PathSize ORDER BY PathSize LIMIT 10"
\\\\ Pointing to the "r" in 'NODES(r)'

Comment: there's another solution? ):